# Ubuntu 14.04 booting stuck at loading screen

Tags: 14.04, boot

I have been using Ubuntu 14.04 for 6 months. Suddenly when I boot up the machine,
the booting process get stuck at Ubuntu's loading splash screen.

[Loading screen img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Gvgn.jpg)

I opened the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F2) and commented out the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` line from the grub and updated it, 
so that I could see the booting process instead of the Ubuntu Splash screen.
From there, I found out that the booting process stops after the following 
command:

```
* Restoring resolver state....       [OK]
* Stopping anac(h)ronistic  crom     [OK]
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated, many thanks!

EDIT:

After rebooting several times, it is seen that the boot does not stops at `Stoopping anac(h)ronistic crom` everytime. Sometimes it stops at

```
saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned
* Restoring resolver state...                     [OK]
* Starting ACPI daemon                            [OK]
* Staring regular background processing daemon    [OK]
* Starting CPU interrupts balancing daemon        [OK]
* Stopping System V runlevel compatibility        [OK]
```

and sometimes at:

```
saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned
 * Restoring resolver state...                  [OK]
 * Starting ACPI daemon                         [OK]
 * Staring regular background processing daemon [OK]
 * Starting CPU interrupts balancing daemon     [OK]
 * Stopping System V runlevel compatibility     [OK]
 * Stopping network connection manager          [OK]
 * Starting SMB/CIFS File and Active Directory Server [OK]
```

Comment: Does it show anything in /var/log/boot.log, /var/log/messages, or /var/log/syslog? If you let it hang there for awhile, does it ever get past that? It could be doing a hard drive scan possibly.

Comment: I was upgrading my 12.04 to 14.04.And the internet connection was disconnected. The upgrading was stopped in half and my lap suddenly shut downed.And when I started my laptop,the loading screen keeps loading.There is somany important data's in my lap.Can u pls solve this issue without losing my data???pls pls pls pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by logging in ( Ctrl+Alt+F2 ) and then upgrading, via `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

I would assume that some of the files somehow got corrupted previously because of some incomplete update or something similar, and upgrading it properly makes everything work as it should.

Comment: Use `sudo apt dist-upgrade` instead, it would help your with retained packages and other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `cron`/`crontab` has problems starting any script.

I only can suggest you to comment all lines in the `crontab` file:

1. Start as root in a command line in the "safe-mode" (sorry, I don't remember the actual name).
2. Execute `crontab -e` and choose the command-line editor if it was not previously choosen.
3. Comment (`#`) every line that is not commented, save the file and exit.
4. Reboot.

EDIT: If, for any reason, the `cron` command doesn't work, the file is `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: I have done it and rebooted it several times, but now the booting does not stop at `Stopping anac(h)ronistic  crom` (more info at edit) It is now stopping at either 
`saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned
....
* Stopping System V runlevel compatibility`

or 

`saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned
* Restoring resolver state...
...
* Stopping System V runlevel compatibility
* Starting network connection manager
Starting SMB/CIFS File and Active Directory Server`

Comment: @rudra Every reboot with a different error? That's very strange.  Try to tail the /var/log/messages and /var/log/syslog, maybe there is something interesting there. (I don't really want to tell you that reinstalling could be the best solution, so I will tell you to try booting from a LiveCD to see if hardware is fine, and it is only a software problem.)

Comment: sorry for the late reply, after rebooting a lot of times, I am making a guess that it is stopping few seconds after  `saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned` is executed, and I am guessing that the exact subtask in which it is stopping (i.e sometimes at `Stopping anac(h)ronistic  crom` and sometimes at `Stopping System V runlevel compatibility` ) is completely random. Not sure about it, but I am just making a guess. Will be posting the messages on /var/log/messages and /var/log/syslog shortly.